# How to specify Solr Cloud collection dynamically in Spring Data Solr 2.0.1?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, spring-data-solr

We are trying to implement a two-dimensional solr cloud cluster where the first dimension is a collection and the second is a shard. Collection should be determined in *runtime* based on a document properties.

I can see that this functionality is supported by solrj- `CloudSolrClient` has appropriate methods which accept collection name like `add(String collection, SolrInputDocument doc)`, so I registered `@Bean CloudSolrClient("zookeeper.host")`. But apparently it isn't enough because methods in `SolrTemplate`, which is used by Spring Data Solr, doesn't accept a collection name.

Since `SolrTemplate` uses `SolrClient` under the hood I tried to workaround this problem extending SolrTemplate and overriding `saveBean` and `saveBeans` methods delegating to `CloudSolrClient#add(String collection, SolrInputDocument doc)` and `CloudSolrClient#add(String collection, Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs)`. It worked fine until I was need to do the same for queries. `SolrTemplate#executeSolrQuery` is package-private and final, so I can't override it. And here I stuck!

To summarise my question: is there a way to specify a collection name in spring data solr in *runtime*?

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Regards,
Eugeny

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a bit different, but I had also a problem with collection name in queries and in my case adding @SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core_to_which_model_class_belong") to model class solved the problem.

Comment: But unfortunately it doesn't seem dynamic. I needed to be able to store documents in different collections, not in a predefined one.

Comment: I was debugging solrj and spring-data-solr code a bit and it seems different solr clients have different approaches. Look at this snippet of code for instance:

    `if (collection == null)`
        `collection = (reqParams != null) ? reqParams.get("collection", getDefaultCollection()) : getDefaultCollection();`

This is from CloudSolrClient. Seems like you need to provide request param to instruct client to execute your call against chosen collection. However I cannot see any method in spring-data-solr to pass a request. It is created inside solrj

Comment: Yes, thanks! I've seen this code too. I ended up implementing queries using solrj.